# Getting E488 errors using Pathogen with Vim

Tags: vim

I'm trying to use Pathogen to manage my vim add-ons under Ubuntu so I can do some rails development but following all the examples leads to a ton of E488 Trailing characters: errors when I run vim.

Here is my .vimrc not that it's much to look at...

```
call pathogen#runtime_append_all_bundles()
```

Has anyone experienced this and if so how did you fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I turned up my scroll buffer so I could see the original error and it ended up being gist.vim which is for some reason an html file..  removing this plugin fixed everything.

Answer (score 2):

It might be that your file is in the wrong format (dos instead of unix).
Try the following:

```
$ dos2unix .vimrc
```